# iCloud syncing Ubiquity error

Tags: ios, icloud

I integrated iCloud in my application and the syncing works, but sometimes I get this error:

```
+[PFUbiquityTransactionLog loadPlistAtLocation:withError:](324): CoreData: Ubiquity:  
Encountered an error trying to open the log file at the location: <PFUbiquityLocation: 
0x1993c0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/ ...
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
(Cocoa error 256 - The item failed to download.)"

-[PFUbiquityTransactionLog loadComparisonMetadataWithError:](220): CoreData: Ubiquity:  
Error encountered while trying to load the comparison metadata for transaction log: 
<PFUbiquityTransactionLog: 0x1a3d60>
transactionLogLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1993c0>: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/
transactionNumber: (null)

Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134302 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
(Cocoa error 134302.)" UserInfo=0x1a50e0 {reason=Error during property list parsing during 
import or opening of log file at location: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x1993c0>:    
/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/ ... Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256  
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256 - The item failed to download.)"
```

No idea what it means, but if I wait a while, it seems that the iCloud merges are done... Anyone an idea how to solve this?

I tried setting

```
[_document.managedObjectContext 
   setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy]
```

but without any help...

Thnx!

Answer (score 3):

This kind of log is just informative.

The iCloud deamon can see that a file is in your ubiquitous container only by getting its meta data. Downloading the file content is a second, separate step.

If it fails to download a file, it will just attempt to download it later.

Comment: I'm seeing very similar errors including "Import operation encountered a corrupt log file". The iCloud deamon keeps retrying every minute or so, but it least in my case, it doesn't seem to be able overcome these errors. However, I have seen cases where errors are resolved on subsequent retries.

Comment: @Daniel did you find a solution? I have the problem that i get every 30 sec a "CoreData: Ubiquity: Error importing transaction log:" error. An the fetch request is blocked.

Comment: @Stephan - Yep I found a solution to this problem: upgrade to iOS 5.1. Although, it is significantly better, I still find that it can take a while to sync (which is sort of acceptable), but then I stop getting notified of changes. However, if I kill the app and restart, I can see the new data. I think closing and opening the UIManagedDocument will also work around the issue, but I've put off doing that in the hopes that a newer iOS version will automagically fix that as well.

Comment: @Daniel thx ... yes i saw the same. Yes i expect iOS6 will fix this :)